# CodeIgniter sessions won't stick on localhost (MAMP)

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, localhost, mamp

It appears that my `CI_Sessions` or even `normal php sessions` **won't stick** on my **localhost**. I'm running **MAMP**.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `MAMP/tmp/php` folder has the right permissions set to it -- most likely it does not.

Another cause for strange session behavior is white space after you close your PHP tag IE:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'this is a test';
?>

[line breaks/spaces]
```

Answer (score 5):

I pulled a site from our live environment and had the same problem. I had to clear the $config['cookie_domain'] value in config.php

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
```